# Can i get result of different query in one aggregation MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I've a collection like this:

[image]

I want to group them by name, and i want get the size of the document for both status `pending` and `done`. I able to get only pending one using `{ match: {status: "pending"}}`.

I want to get the result like this:

```
[{
  id: "Ali",
  pendingOrder: 11,  //status = "pending"
  doneOrder: 10,    // status = "done"
 },
 {
  id:"Henry"
  pendingOrder: 12,
  doneOrder: 20
  },
  ...
]
```

Is it possible to do that in one aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the documents and calculate the count of pending and done orders, conditionally like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "pendingOrders": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status",
                "Pending"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "doneOrders": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status",
                "Done"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wMtKBSSTYvH)